# How to list all files on the system

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew

I would like to list all files on my system from command line.

The provided BSD `find` command, with the following command line

```
sudo find /
```

lists many of the files twice, under the root and under `/System/Volumes/Data`.

The GNU `find` command, installed with Homebrew, with the following command line

```
sudo gfind /
```

does not list files under `/Applications`, `/Users`, `/Volumes` and others.
The command

```
sudo gfind /*
```

lists more file, but I am not sure if they are all.

I would like to list all files once and preferably with GNU `find`, because differently from BSD `find` has a `-printf` command with many output formats, like inode, size, separated path and filename, unified timestamp and others.

Comment: About your last sentence,  try `find / -ls`.

Comment: @lhf, yes, but the output should then be parsed, and still a sortable timestamp is not directly present

Answer (score 1):

My best solution is the following (for bash shell)

```
shopt -s dotglob
for f in /* 
  sudo gfind "$f" -path /System/Volumes/Data -prune -o -print 2>/dev/null
done
shopt -u dotglob
```

where, in place of `-print`, one can use several other commands.

The most part of files in `/System/Volumes/Data` are the same as in `/`, with few and not much interesting additions.

Moreover, the more compact solution `gfind /*` does not work well, because produces many loops that prevent the listing of many parts of the full listing.